# A question about the Iconize command and the Graphics Options

Tags: plotting, legending, iconize

I have the following function:

```
f[t_, s_] := Piecewise[{{{-Sqrt[2 s + t^2], Sqrt[2 s + t^2]}, 
s > 0}, {{-Sqrt[2 s + t^2], Sqrt[2 s + t^2]}, s > 0}}]
```

The corresponding plot with legends for different values of $s$:

[image]

My goal is to get the above result using Iconize. However, I can only get the following:

[image]

In advance, I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? In V12.3, I can [reproduce the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPuQx.png) even with iconized options. How do you generate iconized objects?

Comment: With Iconize[PlotLegends->{ }, "name"] and Iconize[HoldForm@{f[t,1], f[t,3], f[t,5]}, "name"]. My version: 13.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMA version 13.0:

```
f[t_, s_] := 
 Piecewise[{{{-Sqrt[2 s + t^2], Sqrt[2 s + t^2]}, 
    s > 0}, {{-Sqrt[2 s + t^2], Sqrt[2 s + t^2]}, s > 0}}]
Iconize[Plot[{f[t, 1], f[t, 3], f[t, 5]}, {t, -5, 5}]]
```

The output of this is:

[image]

If one clicks on "+" one gets:

[image]

And if one clicks "Uniconize", one gets:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks a lot, Daniel.